# Transform rows to cells

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I need to transform two column

> Table X (ItemNoCol, ItemCol)

to 12 column

```
Table Y
(ItemNoCol1,ItemCol1,ItemNoCol2,ItemCol2,
 ItemNoCol3,ItemCol3,ItemNoCol4,ItemCol4,
 ItemNoCol5,ItemCol5,ItemNoCol6,ItemCol6)
```

like this

Table X data

```
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    D
5    E
6    F
7    G
8    H
9    I
10    J
11    K
12    L
13    M
14    N
15    O
16    P
```

Table Y transformed data

```
1   A   2   B   3   C   4   D   5   E   6   F
7   G   8   H   9   I   10  J   11  K   12  L
13  M   14  N   15  O   16  P
```

What is the best way of doing this. 
Maybe using cursor? Max number of rows in Tablw X is about 1000, so its not a big table, and it will never be.

I am doing this because of reporting in Crystal. What is the best place for this, Crystal or sql server?

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal, you can use Crystal's crosstab functionality to pivot data like this. You would need to have values (either derived in the SQL query or as formulas in the report) for both the modulus and the truncated integer value of the ItemNoCol field divided by the number of columns you want in your output - one to group columns, the other to group rows.